# I don't understand the ArityException when I use a function literal

Tags: clojure

I'm struggling to understand why...

```
(map (fn [x] {:hello x}) ["moe" "larry" "curly"])
=> ({:hello "moe"} {:hello "larry"} {:hello "curly"})
```

...works like a champ but...

```
(map #({:hello %}) ["moe" "larry" "curly"])
ArityException Wrong number of args (0)...
```

...throws `ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentArrayMap  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)`

What am I doing wrong in my function literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the issue if you expand you use of the `#` macro:

```
(macroexpand `#({:hello %}))

=> (fn* [p1__1__2__auto__] ({:hello p1__1__2__auto__}))
```

this returns a function of a single argument which when applied calls the constructed hash map with no arguments, hence the `ArityException` you see when evaluating the sequence returned from `map`. You could use `hash-map` instead of a map literal:

```
(map #(hash-map :hello %) ["moe" "larry" "curly"])
```

Comment: Oh....yuk.  I'm liking function literals less and less.  I had forgotten about macroexpand.  Thanks.

Comment: @BobKuhar - I usually avoid them but the main pitfall I'm aware of is cases like this when constructing data type literals.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion such as you encountered above, I almost never use function literals, always preferring the explicit form you had first:  `(fn [x] ...)`

---

In case this is a more convenient solution, I like to use [the `zip` and `zip-lazy` functions](https://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.core.html#var-zip) for some tasks:

```
(defn zip-lazy
  "Usage:  (zip-lazy coll1 coll2 ...)
      (zip-lazy xs ys zs) -> [ [x0 y0 z0]
                               [x1 y1 z1]
                               [x2 y2 z2]
                               ... ]

  Returns a lazy result. Will truncate to the length of the shortest collection.
  A convenience wrapper for `(map vector coll1 coll2 ...)`.  "
  [& colls]  ; #todo how use Schema with "rest" args?
  (assert #(every? sequential? colls))
  (apply map vector colls))
```

so we can just write:

```
(zip-lazy
  (repeat "hello")
  ["larry" "moe" "curly"])

:result => (["hello" "larry"] 
            ["hello" "moe"] 
            ["hello" "curly"])
```